# SAS Error on ANOVA Code

Tags: anova, sas

I have been having this problem with SAS all year and I can fix it, but it ends up being time-consuming.

Example: When I use the code attached (a simple ANOVA code) I get errors that say I have invalid data for the treatment code. This seems to be because I have denoted the different treatments using A, B, C, D, and E. I can fix this by switching the letters to numbers but I feel like it should be able to run with the letters.

The specific error is: ERROR: One or more variables are missing or freq or weight is zero on every observation.

[image: SAS Code]

The code I am using (pictured with proper format in picture) is:
Data ANOVA3;
input treat val;
cards;
C   96
B   69
D   65
E   34
A   89
C   90
D   74
E   49
B   58
D   41
C   60
A   90
A   106
B   95
E   41
D   54
C   57
A   99
D   35
E   18
C   62
B   78
B   96
E   24
A   71
;
run;
title "problem3";
proc glm;
class treat;
model val= treat;
lsmeans treat / stderr pdiff;
run;